# What is the correct pronunciation of 호박잎?

Tags: pronunciation

Is it /호방닙/ or /호방깁?/ I think it is the first one because of there is an insertion of ㅅ and ㄴ: 호박+ㅅ+ㄴ+잎, the ㅅ disappears and the ㄱ nasalizes under the influence of ㄴ. But in this [children's song recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPX3gCTPRyg&t=662s) all I can hear is 호방깁. (The title of this song is 호박잎 and there are many instances of this word in the lyrics. The song starts at 11:02 in the video, and the lyrics can be viewed [here](https://www.genie.co.kr/detail/songInfo?xgnm=82926434)).

Am I hearing it wrong or is she actually pronuncing it as 호방깁? What is the correct pronunciation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just listened to the linked song - to my ears, the child is clearly singing "호방입", not "호방깁", but the ㅇ sound is longer - almost "geminated" (sort of like how 갔니 /간니/ has a double ㄴ, unlike 가니 with a single ㄴ.)

As for why, I'm not a linguist, so the following is just my guess:

As far as I know, Korean doesn't have a distinction between single vs. double ㅇ (at least in Seoul dialect), but here it seems like we effectively have "ㅇㅇ".  That is, the pronunciation start with /호박/+/입/, then becomes /호박/+/닙/ (사잇소리), then becomes /호방닙/ (assimilation), and then finally the ㄴ sound is assimilated back to ㅇ, resulting in a "double ㅇ" (= /ŋŋ/) sound.

I'm not 100% sure about the process, but the result sounds totally natural to me (native speaker in my 40s, grew up in Seoul area).

- As user67275 said, I believe the *standard* pronunciation is "호방닙", but in everyday speech, the ㄴ due to 사이시옷 is frequently dropped in random places.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I think you and I heard the same thing. The problem was that I did not really know how to write down what I heard. To be more precise, in that recording, the first two syllables are definitely /호방/, but the third one is not a pure /입/, nor is it a /닙/, as there is clearly no ㄴ sound in the recording. Rather, the ㅇ sound in 호방 is somehow connected to /잎/, and my ear picked that up as a little "ㄱ-like" thing before the ㅣ. And without thinking too much I wrote that down as /호방깁/. But I believe we heard the same thing. Your identifying this as a "doube ㅇ" is...(continued)

Comment: ...a great revelation to me as I have never thought in this way before. What I was missing in my reasoning was the assimilation of ㄴ back to ㅇ, which is not taught in my textbook. I 'll try to look for more examples like this.

Comment: Added: Would you say that the same sound occurs in words like 호랑이, 고양이 and 아지랭이? Can I think of those as having double ㅇ also?

Comment: Well I'm just one data point (so plz take it with a large grain of salt), but I just tried saying 호랑이/고양이/아지랑이 with "double ㅇ" and they sound really weird to me. Probably because there's no ㄴ sound to begin with.

Comment: OK. Could you please describe in some detail how the sound in 호랑이/고양이/아지랑이 is supposed to differ from the double ㅇ? That would be immensely helpful to me as I am unable to tell the difference right now.

Comment: Have you guys tried these words: 부엌일/콩잎. They also seem to be bundled with that double ㅇ sound unlike 호랑이/고양이/아지랑이. I have no idea why though. it just pronounces so naturally and in a way I feel the most comfortable with

Comment: @Coconut I accepted this answer as it essentially solves my original question. But I now have problem hearing the difference between the "double ㅇ" sound and the "normal" sound in words like "호랑이". I am going to turn this into another question. Hope you could join in if you have something more to share

Answer (score 1):

It is '호:방닙'

The reference is
https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/cae4df1923d24305b4f27782ba4c41be