# Words like 호랑이/고양이/아지랭이 vs. words like 호박잎/콩잎/부엌일, what is the difference regarding the consonant(s) before the final "ㅣ"?

Tags: pronunciation

It all started with [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPX3gCTPRyg&t=662s) titled 호박잎 (starts at 11:02 in the video, lyrics [here](https://www.genie.co.kr/detail/songInfo?xgnm=82926434)) on Youtube, and I noticed that the singer's pronunciation of 호박잎 is different from the supposed "standard" pronunciation of [호방닙]. So I posted [this question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/6371/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-%ed%98%b8%eb%b0%95%ec%9e%8e) on this very forum, asking for a clarification of the "correct" pronunciation.

As it turns out, some native guy came along and kindly explained that the singer's pronunciation could be perceived as a "double ㅇ" sound (with the ㄴ in [호방닙] assimilated back to ㅇ/ŋ/), and such pronunciation was totally acceptable. Upon seeing this explanation, I thought this "double ㅇ" thing they were referring to must be the same sound in 호랑이/고양이/아지랭이, where the syllable-final ㅇ is somehow connected to ㅣ. But my belief was soon proven otherwise by at least two different people, and they claim that pronuncing 호랑이/고양이/아지랭이 with the "double ㅇ" sounded weird.

So here's the problem: I still cannot **hear** the difference between the "double ㅇ" sound in  words like 호박잎/콩잎/부엌일 and the supposedly "not-double ㅇ" sound in words like 호랑이/고양이/아지랭이, let alone to actually **pronounce** them in different fashion. It would be immensely helpful if someone could shed insight into this. Thank you guys very much!

**Edit** Here's a [link](https://youtu.be/mcNx0suSff8?t=1474) to a song containing the word "아지랭이", it occurs at around 24:43

Comment: I think the case '호박잎/콩잎' and '부엌일' have to be distinguished: I think the pronunciation of ㅇ at the former is closer to /ŋn/, while that at the latter is /k'ŋ/.

Comment: @HanulJeon Could you elaborate? My dictionary says the standard pronunciation of 부엌일 is [부엉닐].

Comment: This is my hunch, so I cannot justify my comment to a full extent. Also, the Korean script may not reflect the full pronunciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me point out that 아지랭이 is a non-standard form of 아지랑이(haze). However, [아지랭이 behaved as it was a standard word for years.](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=140560)
Along with my hunch, it suggests that child songs you listened reflect older standard Korean, not the current one, so it may follow a different pronunciation rule that is obsolete now. (Note that, child songs you linked sound old-fashioned, and this is the reason for my hunch.)

I think sticking on double ŋ presents is a bad idea to understand the pronunciation of the given words. As the previous answer carefully: it is just derived from ㄴ addition as the previous answer pointed out, and the addition ŋ sound is a variant of ㄴ(/n/).

ㄴ addition *can* appear when the given word is a [통사적 합성어](http://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Contents/Item/E0079631). Both 호박잎(호박+잎), 콩잎(콩+잎), and 부엌일(부엌+일) is an example of 통사적 합성어. However, none of 호랑이, 고양이, 아지랑이 is even a compound word.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I understand the rule of ㄴ-insertion, but in [this recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPX3gCTPRyg&t=662s) the word 호박잎 is pronounced with not an ㄴ sound but ŋ as you pointed out. Would you help me understand: (1) if this is also an old-fashioned pronunciation, and (2) is the pronunciation of 호박잎 in this specific recording different from how one would normally pronounce 호랑이 or 고양이?

Comment: @user23823 Would you clarify your comments? First, does it comprise two questions? If were, I can only make a guess for your first question since I have no concrete evidence for old pronunciation of 호박잎 and 아지랭이.

Comment: For the second question (if I get it correctly) I need more elaboration for your question. Are you asking about whether there is any pronunciation change of 호랑이 and 고양이?

Comment: My second question was this: is the pronunciation of 호박잎 **in that recording** the same as the way one would normally pronounce 호랑이 and 고양이? I used to believe so but someone told me otherwise. Basically he said that the recording pronounced 호박잎 with a "double ㅇ" but when he tries to pronounce 호랑이 and 고양이 with the "double ㅇ" it sounded really weird. But I was not able to tell the difference.

Comment: @user23823 Subtle to distinguish for me, but I hear this is not 호바깁, so no.

Comment: Sure, but what about 호랑이 and 고양이? They aren't [호라기] or [고야기] either . Am I right?

Comment: Yes, their pronunciation is *not* [호라기] and [고야기]. There is no reason to appear ㄱ unlike 호박잎 (ㄱ of 박, which is changed to final ㅇ sound due to ㄴ addition.)

Comment: Understood. Then what about the difference between 호박잎 (as in the song's recording) and 호랑이? Subtle to distinguish?

Comment: I assume you are not asking about why the difference occurs since I and other answers explained it a lot. I also hear that the last sound of 호박잎 in your linked song is similar to that of 호랑이 (so both of them hears like ~ŋi~, not like either kŋi, nŋi or ŋŋi.) The pronunciation in the song is quite subtle, however, which makes me not sure about it.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your careful explanation. I guess this is a weird question to begin with, and I really appreciate your willingness to follow along. I am going to award a bounty to both of the two answers here. If possible.

Comment: Can't approve of this as an answer. This guy is not even recognizing the sound we were discussing in the previous question. This has nothing to do with 합성어 and language rules. It's about **pronunciation** and to tell the sound produced.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a composed word to make ㄴ addition.

호박잎 = 호박(pumpkin) + 잎(leaf)

콩잎 = 콩(bean) + 잎(leaf)

부엌일 = 부엌(kitchen) + 일(work, chore)

and it doesn't have to be double ㅇ.
꽃잎[꼰닙] would be the case.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for replying so late. I understand the ㄴ addition that you are referring to. But in the [recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPX3gCTPRyg&t=662s) the word 호박잎 is pronounced with no ㄴ sound. I used to believe that the sound **in the recording** was the same as in 호랑이 or 고양이, but some native guy came along and told me that it was different, and now I am confused.

Comment: @user23823 I guess the singer is taking the lyric as '호박 잎' instead of '호박잎'. In this case, it is two words so no ㄴ addition. Since both of them still have same meaning, Koreans do not make distinctions between them.(That's why lyrics you linked use '호박잎). For normal use, (not for scholarship or news anchor) it is okay to take both pronunciations right .

Comment: Thanks. I have never thought about this possibility before, but it sounds interesting. May I assume you are a native speaker of Korean? It's intriguing how different people can have different ideas even as native speakers.

Comment: @user23823 Yes I am a native Korean. Wrong pronunciation happens at many words in daily conversation so I recommend you not to apply standard rules for every single word.

Answer (score 0):

I googled a bit and found that that double ㅇ thing jick was referring to is called [성문 파열음(聲門破裂音, glottal stop)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop).

The symbol that represents this sound are [`ʔ`] in the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) and
the Korean letter [`ㆆ`(된이응)](https://ko.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%86%86) which has been obsolete and existed before modern Korean.

Although their current writing system can't express such a sound, some Korean words still have it verbally as of this day.

- 일(一) has this pronunciation but 일(業) does not.
- 호박잎/콩잎/부엌일 has this pronunciation whereas 호랑이/고양이/아지랭이 does not.
- In 동남방언, `E`(이) has this pronunciation but `2`(이) does not.

  - [Youtube video explaining "2의 E승"](https://youtu.be/lx6vLNsOjO0?t=26).

Neither [`ŋŋ`] nor [`ᅇ`(쌍이응)](https://ko.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%85%87) denotes this sound. I'm guessing that the ㄱ-like sound you heard may be one thing and the `된소리` jick heard is another.

I'm not an expert in this area so as to why I can't really give you clear details. How does one sound differ from the other? I honestly don't know. It just does.